# swift4 JSONDecoder. How to decode an array with different type inside?

Tags: swift4

JSON to decode:

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": [
    {
      "code": 1,
      "message": "error"
    },
    [
      {
        "gid": "123"
        ....
      }
    ]
    ....
  ]
}
```

"JSONSerialization" is complex to decode this json.

```swift
let str = """
{"jsonrpc": "2.0","result": [{"code": 1,"message": "error"},[{"gid": "123"}]]}
"""
let data = str.data(using: .utf8)!

if let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any],
    let result = json["result"] as? [Any] {
    let error = result.map { $0 as? [Any] }.filter { $0 != nil }
    let objs = result.map { $0 as? [String: Any] }.filter { $0 != nil }

    print(error)
    print(objs)
}
```

Is there a way to decode the JSON payload with JSONDecoder to [Data] or anything else.

```swift
struct Result: Codable {
    let result: [???]   //can't use [Data] here
}
```

Comment: If your data isn't structured maybe `[String : Any]` is the way to go

Comment: Can you post the complete JSON?

Comment: The complete json is same to the example. There is dictionarys and arrays in the array named "result". "Any" does not conform Codable.

Comment: I know it's not, I meant using it with JSONSerialization. Is the JSON structure known and stable ? You'll probably need to implement`encode(:)` and `init(:) throws`

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to decode the JSON payload with JSONDecoder to [Data] or anything else.

The `decode` method on `JSONDecoder` requires some type that conforms to `JSONDecodable`. True, `Any` does not conform to `Decodable` and neither does `Data` or `[Data]`. You probably want to define a custom Swift type to represent your JSON and make *that* conform to `Decodable`.

> How to decode an array with different type inside?

The reason we want to see the complete JSON is that it is useful to know whether the dictionaries and arrays inside `result` are consistent. If the entries are all like your example, then perhaps you could do something like this:

```
struct JSONRPC: Decodable {
    enum Result: Decodable {
        struct ArrayItem: Decodable {
            let code: Int
            let message: String
        }
        case array([ArrayItem])
        case dictionary(Dictionary<String, String>)
        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            // Implement decoder for enum with associated values.
            // This will not "just work" without your additional
            // instructions specifying how to do it. But that's an
            // answer for a separate question, I think.
        }
    }
    let version: String
    let results: [Result]
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case version = "jsonrpc"
        case results = "result"
    }
}
```

With that in place, you can use it like this:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let payload = try decoder.decode(JSONRPC.self, from: data)
```

If the decoding succeeds, then payload will be an instance of `RPCJSON`.